# Moving Sass inside /src Breaks (using webpack)

Tags: webpack, sass

So my sass folder is outside of my /src folder like so:

```
/sass
/src
webpack.config.js
```

It is imported in my code like so from my src/main.js

```
import '../sass/global.scss';
```

The problem is I want to move my sass into my /src folder. So I do then I change my import to `import './sass/global.scss';` and then run the webpack build again but this time I will get:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"importLoaders":2}!./~/postcss-loader/lib?{}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/sass/modules/_response-control.scss
    Module build failed: 
      border-top: 1px solid darken($gray-lighter, 20%);
                                  ^
          Undefined variable: "$gray-lighter".
          in /Users/allen/work/src/sass/modules/_response-control.scss (line 9, column 32)
```

This is my sass rules in webpack config:

```
test: [/\.scss$/, /\.sass$/],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {}
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader'
      },
    ],
  }),
```

What would make it work its outside of the src folder but not when it is inside src folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe weparck configuration is fine, as you are not using include / exclude properties, so it will process the /src folder using the sass-loader.

The problem I think you are facing is about paths inside your scss files.

Comment: You are right its imports my resolve is like so resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
  }. so sass doing @import "base/file.scss" isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$gray-lighter` could be a variable imported from another sass file - when you moved the `_response-control.scss` file were it's imports still correct?